# Is there a function for closing app on mouse or keyboard movement in Python

Tags: python, tkinter, pywin32

I want my **Tkinter** app to close when **keyboard or mouse movement** is detected. I made a simple version in console, and it works as expected. However, when implementing this into a window app, it does not detect anything, only when I close the app in ALT+F4. Below was the implantation for console. I want this to work specifically in a window as I am trying to build a screensaver type app.

```
for i in range(100):
    a = int(win32api.GetLastInputInfo())
    print(win32api.GetLastInputInfo())
    time.sleep(0.5)

    if win32api.GetLastInputInfo() == a:
        print("Idle")
    else:
        print("Mouse or keyboard input received!")
```

Comment: You can bind `<Key>` and `<Motion>` to a callback and then destroy the root window inside the callback.

Answer (score 0):

You can automate movements of mouse and keyboard using pyautogui module in python. This module is not preloaded with python. So to install it run the following command:
pip3 install pyautogui

For quitting the running code we can use this..
pyautogui.hotkey('ctrl','c')

Comment: When doing this, the window never actually opens, it just prints the numbers, and goes on forever. Here is the full code: https://pastebin.com/ryACJrfp

Comment: pyautogui.hotkey('ctrl','c') is pressing of Ctrl+C in the code way like we can assume it as a keyboard movement.
what if we implement it in a condition like:
if expresssion == pyautogui.hotkey('ctrl','c')
it detects key board movement and then you can use any stop command after this line..

Comment: So what exactly would I have to put in the "expression" part?

Comment: Plus, from what I've tried, it is not detected any input, keyboard or mouse...